# JavaFX apllication does not run with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, javafx, automation, phantomjs

I want to use Selenium WebDriver in JavaFX application that I want to get a screenshot of a webpage and show it in ImageView in JavaFX app.

This code works completely fine to take screenshot of webpage and save it:

```
package application;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("E:\\Eclipse_Projects\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());

        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");

        // taking screenshot
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("screenshot.png"));

        driver.close();

        System.out.println("Done!");    
    }
}
```

In order to use the saved screenshot in JavaFX app I tried to make some simple modifications to this class to make it a JavaFX app.

Here is the modified code:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File file = new File("E:\\Eclipse_Projects\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\\phantomjs.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.14.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());

        WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");

        // taking screenshot
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File("screenshot.png"));

        driver.close();

        System.out.println("Done!");

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

This is one of the simplest JavaFX applications with some code in main method and when I run it, it should save the screenshot and open a blank JavaFX app. But when I run it, it does not do anything, it does not even execute the main method. It gets terminated after 1-2 seconds without doing anything.

Then I realized that JavaFX application does not run when Selenium Webdriver library is in the build path. That even if I delete all Selenium stuff from the class, it ends up with the same problem.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

The code above runs only when I delete Selenium WebDriver library from the project's build path.

I have tried these in two IDEs:
In Eclipse, the program gets terminated after 1-2 seconds without doing anything and without any error.
In NetBeans, the program gets terminated after 1-2 seconds without doing anything but it gives me an error:

```
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: -1073740791
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

It is almost 2 years that I am writing code in Java, but it is the first time that I come across such a problem. I googled a lot and didn't find anything similar to this.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here and what is the problem? Any idea would be appreciated.

Edit: it works normally when I run the generated jar-file outside of IDE.

Thanks for consideration.

Comment: Just a small hint, because I am on the same topic: https://github.com/anthavio/phanbedder use that dependency for having phantomjs being part of your application ... did you try execution the generated jar-file outside of your IDE?

Comment: @FibreFoX, thanks for your comment. I just tried to execute the generated jar-file and it worked normally. I think the problem is with IDE.

Comment: @yalchin.av - I quickly tried using your sample and I am not able to reproduce your issue. The JavaFx application works (I dont know much about JavaFx, but I do know a fair bit about Selenium). Perhaps you might want to share your dependencies (I work with Maven)... I have selenium 3.0.1 in my classpath. FWIW, I use IntelliJ

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan - I work with a normal java project(not maven) and I have selenium 3.0.1 in my classpath. I am going to try IntelliJ, perhaps it is an IDE related issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the reason of this issue. The problem is related to the NVIDIA Driver. I was using version 378.49 and I rolled back to version 376.33. Now, the problem is solved. You can see more details on https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000060510-Process-finished-with-exit-code-1073740791-0xC0000409-JavaFX-Application

Thanks to @KrishnanMahadevan for reminding me to use IntelliJ IDE.