# Java Eclipse <terminated, exit value: -1073740791>

Tags: java, eclipse, terminate

```
<terminated, exit value: -1073740791>C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe
```

I receive the above message when I attempt to debug why my code is suddenly terminating without error in Eclipse. I am able to run the exact same code on a different machine with a different installation of Eclipse Neon.

Based on debugging I've found that it terminates at the following statement

```
bot = new Robot();
```

Things I've tried...

- Reinstalling Eclipse Neon (after removing eclipse folder)
- Reinstalling Java (Both JDK and JRE)
- Adjusting PATH variables
- Removing local git clone and pulling code again
- Restarting Computer (really just shooting in the dark now)

I have a feeling it has something to do with this specific eclipse settings as the code runs perfectly fine on another machine/eclipse setup.

Thanks in advance for any/all help.

Comment: Are you by any chance loading anything for a properties file or looking for anything in a class path perhaps?

Comment: yalchin.av hit the nail on the head. It was indeed NVIDIA Drivers that were causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same exit value (-1073740791) while writing javaFX application in NetBeans and IntelliJ. My problem was solved when I rolled back the NVIDIA Driver from version 378.49 to the version 376.33. You can see more details on [JavaFX apllication does not run with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42170514/javafx-apllication-does-not-run-with-selenium-webdriver/42188015#42188015)

Comment: Wow, I would never have figured that out. I just updated to 378.66 and program runs just fine now! Thanks for your help!